# Why does the br tag not move the text under the title?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I get the text that says "this is just some placeholder text that should let you scroll" to be under the title? I thought seeing as there is a `<br>` tag after the title, the text would go under it?

(in case it's unclear in the snippet, the background image has an arrow pointing down, indicating that the user should scroll down upon arriving at the home page).

```js
$(document ).ready(function(){
    var counter = 0;
    $('#menuIcon').click(function(){
        counter+=1;
        
        if (counter == 3){
            
            
        }
        
        
        
    });
        
        
    
    
    
});

var open = false;

function Drop(n) {
    var i;
    if (open == false) {
        for (i = n; i < 5; i++) {
            Drp(i)
        }
        open = true
    } else if (open == true) {
        for (i = n; i < 5; i++) {
            Cls(i)
        }
        open = false
    }
}

function Drp(n) {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-con")[n];
    var pos = -1 * window.innerHeight - n * 100;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

    function frame() {
        if (pos >= -10) {
            clearInterval(id);
            elem.style.top = 0 + 'px';
        } else {
            pos += 10;
            elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
        }
    }
}

function Cls(n) {
    var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-con")[n];
    var poss = 0;
    var ids = setInterval(frames, 5);

    function frames() {
        if (poss <= -1 * window.innerHeight) {
            clearInterval(ids);
            elems.style.top = -1 * window.innerHeight + 'px';
        } else {
            poss += -7 - n * 2;
            elems.style.top = poss + 'px';
        }
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
    background-image:url(foo.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}


.menuBox {
    display: none;
    
}

.menuBox a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}

.menu-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 10px 15px;
    transform: scale(0.8);
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 20
}

.menu-bar {
    width: 50px;
    height: 5px;
    background: rgb(190, 190, 190);
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 50px
}

.menu-bar1 {
    margin-top: 9px
}

.menu-bar2 {
    margin-top: 23px
}

.menu-bar3 {
    margin-top: 37px
}

.menu-icon.hover .menu-bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) scaleX(0.7);
    margin-top: 22px;
}

.menu-icon.hover .menu-bar2 {
    opacity: 0
}

.menu-icon.hover .menu-bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scaleX(0.7);
    margin-top: 22px;
}

.menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu-con {
    -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    position: relative;
    top: -100%;
    transition: all 0.5s
}

.menu-con a:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.menu-con:hover a:before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

.menu-con a {
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-align-self: center;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    z-index: 2;
    cursor: pointer
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu-con {
        min-width: 50%
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    .menu-con {
        min-width: 100%
    }
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.title {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items:center;
    font-size:50px;
    color:white;
}
.homeText {
    background-color:darkblue;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<html class="animated pulse">
    <head>
    <title>Ben Cohen</title>
    <link href=style.css rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="animate.css" rel=stylesheet>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <link rel=icon href=icon.png>
</head>

<body>

    
    <div class="menu-icon" onclick="this.classList.toggle('hover');Drop(0)" id="menuIcon">
        <div class="menu-bar menu-bar1"></div>
        <div class="menu-bar menu-bar2"></div>
        <div class="menu-bar menu-bar3"></div>
    </div>


    <div class="menu">

        <div class="menu-con" style="background:red;" href="yayitworks.html">
            <a href="index.html">HOME</a>
        </div>

        <div class="menu-con" style="background:blue" id="hello">
            <a>PORTFOLIO</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-con" style="background:darkorange;">
            <a>POUS</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-con" style="background:green;">
            <a>HOMEWORK</a>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-con" style="background:white;">
            <a style="color:black">TEST PAGE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="homeText">
    <div class="title">
    THIS IS A TITLE.
    </div><br>
    <p>this is just some placeholder text that should let you scroll</p>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: class "hometext" has css  `display: flex;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `display: flex;` from your .hometext CSS.

```
.hometext {
    background-color:darkblue;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

You can also specify the flex direction:

```
.hometext {
    background-color:darkblue;
    justify-content:center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
```

More info here...
https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css3_flexbox.asp
& here...
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex